# Picture selecting with duration

Tags: c#

Hello I am currently coding an app to practice gesture drawing, the app works with I am downloading pictures into a folder and then with duration of 60 second it will import a picture in order or randomly into picturebox. How can I do that?  [It currently looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVKeG.png)

Answer (score 1):

you need to use a timer control. Then point the event handler of the timer to a function that draws a new image

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer?view=windowsdesktop-6.0

This is assuming you are using Winforms